# NserviceBus property injection

Tags: inversion-of-control, nservicebus

I am attempting to inject an object into my saga. Using the following endpoint, when the message arrives at the handle method of the saga the property is null.

The endpoint:

```
 public class EndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint, AsA_Server,  IWantToRunAtStartup
        {
            public void Run()
            {
                IOrderRepository orderRepository = new OrderRepository();
                Configure.Instance.Configurer.ConfigureProperty<CreateOrderSaga>(x => x.OrderRepository, orderRepository);
            }

// stop method removed
    }
```

The app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="MsmqTransportConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.MsmqTransportConfig, NServiceBus.Core" />
    <section name="UnicastBusConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.UnicastBusConfig, NServiceBus.Core" />
  </configSections>

  <MsmqTransportConfig
    InputQueue="Fulfilment.CreateOrder.OrderRecievedMessage"
    ErrorQueue="error"
    NumberOfWorkerThreads="1"
    MaxRetries="3"
  />

  <UnicastBusConfig
   DistributorControlAddress=""
   DistributorDataAddress="">
    <MessageEndpointMappings>
      <add Messages="NServiceBus.Saga.TimeoutMessage, NServiceBus" Endpoint="timeoutmanager" />
    </MessageEndpointMappings>
  </UnicastBusConfig>
</configuration>
```

and my Saga accepting messages as follows

```
    public class CreateOrderSaga : Saga<CreateOrderSagaData>,
            IAmStartedByMessages<OrderRecievedMessage>,
            IHandleMessages<OrderCompletedMessage>,
            IHandleMessages<OrderCancelledMessage>
        {
            public IOrderRepository OrderRepository { get; set; }
            public void Handle(OrderRecievedMessage message)
            {
var order = new Order();
 OrderRepository.SaveOrder(order);
            }
```

a null reference expection will be thrown when attempting to call SaveOrder(). Have i configured the dependency injection correctly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NServiceBus will automatically do property injection for you so you only need to register your repository with the container:

In your `Init()` method: (Implement `IWantCustomInitialization` on a separate class)

```
Configure.Instance.ConfigureComponent< OrderRepository >([The lifecycle you want]);
```

`IWantToRunAtStartup` is not meant for configuration tasks (use `IWantCustomInitialization` instead)

Comment: There's now a shortened form of that with just: Configure.Component<T>(lifecycle);